# Confusion on Start-Job for File Share

Tags: powershell

So, this is absolutely whipping me.  I have created a script that moves data based on a user's response to an number of questions from one file share to another.  What I would like to do is have a background job running that provides a report of all the files being moved prior to the move taking place.  As a result, I added this little bit of code that absolutely doesn't gather info from the source file share.  It simply provides data from my particular machine.  What am I doing wrong?

```
While ($sourcepath -eq $null) {
$sourcepath= read-host "Enter source file path"
}
Set-Location $sourcepath
Start-job -Scriptblock {Get-childitem -recurse |Out-File 
c:\users\john.smith\desktop\shareonfile.txt}
```

Answer (score 1):

Jobs run in a different process, with their own scope. The working directory won't be inherited. To demonstrate this:

```
Set-Location $sourcepath

Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    Get-Location
} | Wait-Job | Receive-Job

Get-Job | Remove-Job
```

You should avoid setting the location anyway, and just pass the path to `Get-ChildItem`. To do that in a job, define a parameter and pass its value like so:

```
Start-job -Scriptblock { param($thePath)
    Get-childitem -Path $thePath -recurse | 
    Out-File c:\users\john.smith\desktop\shareonfile.txt
} -ArgumentList $sourcepath
```

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you so much.  That makes perfect sense.